# Setting environment variables for IHostEnvironment in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application

Tags: c#, .net, appsettings

I am working on a .NET Framework (not Core) application, but am implementing an `IHost` and `IHostBuilder` style startup.  I am attempting to use the `IHostEnvironment` to load different configurations based upon the `HostBuilderContext`'s understanding of the environment:

```
 host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
      {
       IHostEnvironment env = context.HostingEnvironment;

       config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
       config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json, true, true);
      })
...
```

In a .NET Core application, you can set the *DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT* (or *ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT*) variable within the Project Properties file in the Visual Studio UI, or you can set it within the `launchSettings.json` file of the project.  All documentation that I can find regarding this topic relates to implementing it this way.

A full .NET Framework 4.7.2 project does not have the option for updating environment variables in the project setting UI, and does not use a launch settings file.

What is the appropriate way to update the *DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT* variable within a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application so that the `IHostEnvironment` variable can be used effectively?

Comment: Launch settings is just for launching while debugging, really. Visual studio framework projects have a debug tab in the properties dialog. You can set environment variables there. Otherwise in production-like scenario you would set them as if any other environment variables (set/setx or the system properties dialogs)

Comment: Actually, you can't set environment variables in the debug tab of the properties dialog in a full .net framework project.  The settings just don't exist.  You can only do that if the project type is a .net core project.  That's part of the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the "official" or "appropriate" way, but it should work. I seem to recall doing this several years back when .NET Core was 1.0, but I was still working in Framework.

Call [AddEnvironmentVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.environmentvariablesextensions.addenvironmentvariables?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2) from your `ConfigureAppConfiguration`.

```c#
...
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        ...
        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
```

Then when debugging locally, you have several options.

- Run VS with one of the usual `*_ENVIRONMENT` variables already set; these will then propagate to your app when debugging, or
- Create a shim `.bat` file, set the variable there, and then call your app. Set that as the program to run inside of the project properties (<kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd> on project node in VS) for the main app.

You can augment the above by creating build configurations (beyond Debug and Release) for each environment (e.g. a `Development` configuration), that set an MSBuild property that could be passed to your startup shim. That's to taste though... some developers don't like this idea of extra configurations.

Finally, and this part is a bit speculative, but ultimately any configuration item is sourced from a configuration provider (e.g. JSON file, environment variable, a persistence store like SQL server, etc.) You could actually set this value in one of those or write a custom provider that sets the value. In other words `*_ENVIRONMENT` *don't have to be environment variables at all*.

All of the above should translate nicely when you need to deploy beyond your machine, so long as your build pipeline is setup to source those variables correctly.